# Nginx rewrite of URL with and without trailing slash

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am using the Nginx annotations in Helm like so:

```
ingress:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  hosts:
    - host: "example.com"
      paths:
        - path: /api(/?)(.*)
```

When visiting `example.com/api/`, my URL is rewritten as expected and I am forwarded to my application.

However, when the trailing slash is omitted, e.g `example.com/api`, this no longer is the case. What could I do to ensure that the scenario without a trailing slash included is correctly evaluated?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are searching for regex alternatives?

```
ingress:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  hosts:
    - host: "example.com"
      paths:
        - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
```

Either after `/api` there's another `/` with whatever (captured by the `$2`) or there is the end of the line, which will make `/api` be rewritten to `/`.

Comment: Hi, apologies for me not clarifying earlier, but I would like `/api` to rewrite to `/api/`, not to `/`

Comment: @aclue I see. Just to understand completely, what are you expecting if I request `/api/bbb`? Do you expect `/api/bbb` or `/bbb`?

Comment: The only endpoint I am currently concerned with is `/api`. I've been using the following to redirect this specific endpoint with the following, which appears to be working so far: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: rewrite ^(/api)$ $1/ redirect;`

Comment: Ok but I was asking because I didn't get the problem. If the path needs to keep `/api` you could just use as rewrite-target `/api/$2`. If only `/api` needs to keep the api part while the other subpaths need to remove it, I would probably just write two different Ingress to have 2 completely different configurations.

Comment: To clarify again, I do not want to keep `/api` as is, I just want to append a trailing slash to `/api` such that if I were to visit, `http://example.com/api`, I would be redirected to `http://example.com/api/`

Comment: And if you put `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/$2`, does it work?

Comment: No, I believe this will just rewrite to `/api/api` when I do include the trailing slash. So far the configuration snippet has been working the best thus far, but if it were possible to achieve this without using it that would also be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add another path for that specific endpoint in your `paths` array:

```
ingress:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  hosts:
    - host: "example.com"
      paths:
        - path: /api
        ...
        - path: /api(/?)(.*)
        ...
```

If you are using K8s 1.18 or later you can take advantage of [`pathType`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types)

```
ingress:
  hosts:
    - host: "example.com"
      paths:
        - path: /api
          pathType: Prefix
```

Comment: Hi, after trying this, it appears this did not work as expected. Whether I do or don't specify `/api` in the paths array, the URL is still rewritten by my current nginx controller - it's just that the files which it is trying to serve a directory level deeper are not found and ultimately return a 404 error.

Comment: What K8s version are using?

Comment: So basically `/api` will work for a single page only, that's why you will get 404s for children pages. But also depends on what your application is doing in the backend.